# How to change the Mini Etsy background color and text color?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, etsy

I'm using blogger and decided to add etsy to it. I found an old interactable plugin to show the etsy shop and it worked perfectly. Here is the [Reddit link for reference.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Etsy/comments/7m7y0l/has_the_etsy_mini_code_gone_away/)

The code snippet that displays Etsy store:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.etsy.com/assets/js/etsy_mini_shop.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>new Etsy.Mini(----------,'gallery',3,3,0,'https://www.etsy.com');</script>
```

This creates a 3x3 grid and all items can be clicked, however it is white, and I'd like it another color. The text says the name of the store in red, which is fine, but it would be nice to change it or the font.

I decided to look at [the source.](https://www.etsy.com/assets/js/etsy_mini_shop.js)

```
(function(t){var e={};function i(r){if(e[r])return e[r].exports;var n=e[r]={i:r,l:false,exports:{}};t[r].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,i);n.l=true;return n.exports}i.m=t;i.c=e;i.d=function(t,e,r){i.o(t,e)||Object.defineProperty(t,e,{enumerable:true,get:r})};i.r=function(t){"undefined"!==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(t,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"});Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:true})};i.t=function(t,e){1&e&&(t=i(t));if(8&e)return t;if(4&e&&"object"===typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var r=Object.create(null);i.r(r);Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:true,value:t});if(2&e&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var n in t)i.d(r,n,function(e){return t[e]}.bind(null,n));return r};i.n=function(t){var e=t&&t.__esModule?function e(){return t["default"]}:function e(){return t};i.d(e,"a",e);return e};i.o=function(t,e){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,e)};i.p="https://site.etsystatic.com/ac/evergreenVendor/js/en-US/";var r;try{r=window}catch(n){r=self}r.__webpack_public_path__&&(i.p=window.__webpack_public_path__);return i(i.s="2fbN")})({"2fbN":function(t,e,i){"use strict";window.Etsy="undefined"===typeof window.Etsy?{}:window.Etsy;window.Etsy.Mini=function(t,e,i,r,n,s){this.shop_id=t;this.image_type=e;this.base_url=s;this.rows=r;this.columns=i;this.is_featured=n;this.options={thumbnail_height:94,gallery_height:195};this.init()};window.Etsy.Mini.prototype={init(){this.renderIframe()},renderIframe(){const t=this.getUrl();const e=this.getHeight();const i=this.getWidth();const r=`<iframe frameborder="0" src="${t}" width=${i} height=${e}></iframe>`;document.write(r)},getUrl(){return`${this.base_url}/mini.php`+`?shop_id=${this.shop_id}&image_type=${this.image_type}&rows=${this.rows}&columns=${this.columns}&featured=${this.is_featured}`},getHeight(){const t=50;return this.isGallery()?t+this.rows*this.options.gallery_height:t+this.rows*this.options.thumbnail_height},getWidth(){return this.isGallery()?this.columns*this.options.gallery_height:this.columns*this.options.thumbnail_height},isGallery(){return"gallery"===this.image_type}};(function(){var t=new Image;t.src="https://www.etsy.com/images/1x1.gif?JS_CULL=etsy_mini_shop"})()}});
//# sourceMappingURL=https://www.etsy.com/sourcemaps/evergreenVendor/en-US/etsy_mini_shop.5137fe7a34f9210c3b04.js.map
```

I'm stumped. I know Python well enough, but this isn't my forte. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I implemented the gadget, but I don't know how to customize it.